# Store xml result as .xml file

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

By using the query:

```
SELECT CAST([RESULT] as xml) 
  FROM [dbo].[EVENT_RESULTS] 
 WHERE RESULT_TYPE=21 
   AND ANNUALIZATION_ID = 1
```

I produced an **xml output** with of course multiple lines. Now I simply want to store this output **as .xml file** in the c: folder.
The output looks as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd3dH.png)

If I klick on it, it is declared as a .xml file. But how can I store this result automatically when I run the SQL script? I don't want to do the storage "by hand", since the SQL code will be part of a BATCH Programm.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you considered the [bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility)? It is usually installed as part of the SQL Server setup.

Comment: Hi @Sander. I tried, but I'm struggling with the right code.

`SET @cmd = 'bcp.exe "(SELECT CAST([RESULT] as xml) FROM [dbo].[EVENT_RESULTS] WHERE RESULT_TYPE=21 AND ANNUALIZATION_ID = 1)" queryout D:\AEDT\DATA\TEXT.xml -x -T';
EXEC xp_cmdshell  @cmd`  ; does generate an error message (SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2)

Comment: Nice attempt, you can update your question with it (something like "_I tried this..._") and also add your error message ("_but I get this error..._"). For the error in question, a quick Google search already gave me [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2ad0e8e-78c2-4248-ac03-9609ed8b5a8c/bcp-sql-server-express?forum=Vsexpressinstall).

Comment: Click on the XML in SSMS and do File->Save or CTRL+S to save as XML file on your C drive.

If you need all the rows in one XML you could do something like the answer by user* .

Comment: @MikaelEriksson sorry my issue description was unclear. I'll changed it now. It want the storage of this result as part of the SQL code.

Comment: That is not possible unless you have the server on your machine. Or at least hard. If SQL Server is to create the file the user configured to execute SQL Server (not the user executing the query) has to have access to the drive where you want your file.
What you usually do is that you have a client doing queries against SQL Server and that client then saves the XML to a file.

Comment: bcp as sugested above is a client it is not SQL Server. SSMS is client. You can write your own client in some development tool or you can write a script or something.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson that's a pity but thank you anyway! I'll write a BATCH file to get these results as txt file via "sqlcmd" and convert it back to xml afterwards by means of Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

This is Working in MSSQL Server

```
select * from TableNamefor Xml RAW('Rec'),elements XSINIL,root('Data')
```

Comment: OP has no issue selecting the data, but wants to save the result to a .xml file.

Comment: This query generate result as XML format but you can save manually

Comment: "Saving manually" is not part of the OP's question.

Comment: @user13581111 yes this is not the issue. The result as XML is already generated, but I want to store this solution as a .xml file (.txt file is ok as well) in the folder D:\....